# 4 elements are named x,y,z,w now how to name 8 elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, terminology

I have a vector of four elements. The elements are named `x, y, z, w`:

```
Vec4(x, y, z, w)
```

Now I have another vector of eight elements:

```
Vec8(x, y, z, w, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Now how do you name the additional elements? What's the best practice for naming?

Comment: Are `p, q, r, s` acceptable names?

Comment: Would $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6, x_7, x_8$ work?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Your suggestion makes more sense. I'm expanding an existing code and I wanted to keep the `x,y,z,w` thing. But now I think I'd better move away from the previous naming. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this, $x=(x_1, \cdots , x_n)$.

Much easier to work with than $(x,y,z,w)$.

Comment: Yes. Your approach makes more sense.